# How to create custom shortcut on homescreen with extras parameters?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I would like you create custom separate shortcuts to MPV player for each of my IP cameras around the house.

I can launch MPV to directly play the camera stream using adb

```
adb shell am start -n is.xyz.mpv/is.xyz.mpv.MPVActivity -e filepath "rtsp://login:password@192.168.2.1:554//Streaming/Channels/1"`
```

I tried editing sqlite db `/data/data/org.lineageos.trebuchet/databases/launcher.db` and adding new entry for each shortcut but it didn't work. I'm not 100% sure how to pass extras variable in format like

```
Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=is.xyz.mpv/.MPVActivity;s.filepath=rtsp://login:password@192.168.2.1:554//Streaming/Channels/1;end
```

Comment: It seems that you have root access, given that you can edit that database. In that case, why don't you use Tasker app? You can setup a shortcut (as many as you want) with that first command of yours.

Comment: @Firelord thanks, that looks like it could achieve what I want, but it seems Tasker is paid app. It is somewhat ridiculous such a basic feature is so hard to achieve - creating shortcuts with arguments is a basic feature that normal desktop OS have built-in for decades.

Comment: The app Automate (Llama labs) as well as Terminal Emulator also has a 1x1 widget where you can attach your commands.